# Devices with IPV6 addresses can't access website hosted on azure vm

Tags: nginx, azure-virtual-machine

I have a website made in django with nginx server hosted on azure vm (ubuntu os). The problem is devices which have IPV6 ip addresses can't access my website. "The website took too long to respond" error message appears.
How to solve this problem?
Are changes required on azure side or nginx side?
Thanks

Comment: By default nginx is configured to listen to IPV6 and Can you share the error messages that you are receiving.